# Convert scalar function to table function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a scalar function that returns a value from a select statement if it returns a value for the appropriate variables. If there is no return value, the scalar function returns one of the input parameters as the result.

How can I solve this in a table function?

Can I may be use this:

```
WITH Param
AS (
    SELECT ID
        ,Data
    FROM Configuration
    WHERE NAME = 'NameOfConfiguration'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL
        ,'Default Value'
    )
SELECT TOP 1 Data
FROM Param
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

instead of this:

```
IF (LEN(ISNULL(@returnvalue, '')) = 0)
BEGIN
    RETURN @thisvalue
END

RETURN @returnvalue
```

Comment: I have tried to use the code above in table function but It does not work

Comment: Your code works fine for me - what is the issue you see?

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me too. Maybe you are having issues with the TVF declaration syntax? Please add the actual CREATE FUNCTION statement as you are trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Table valued function and scalar valued functions are entirely different.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This link would give you how to create table valued and scalar functions.

Please feel to revert back if you have need more clarification :)